# How to modify configuration file with Python

Tags: python, replace, sed

I am trying to modify a configuration file using Python. How can I do the equivalent of multiple sed commands in this format:

```
sed -ci 's/ServerTokens OS/ServerTokens Prod/' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

most efficiently in Python? This is what I am doing right now:

```
with open("httpd.conf", "r+") as file:
    tmp = []
    for i in file:
        if '#ServerName' in i:
            tmp.append(i.replace('#ServerName www.example.com', 'ServerName %s' % server_name , 1))
        elif 'ServerAdmin' in i:
            tmp.append(i.replace('root@localhost', webmaster_email, 1))
        elif 'ServerTokens' in i:
            tmp.append(i.replace('OS', 'Prod', 1))
        elif 'ServerSignature' in i:
            tmp.append(i.replace('On', 'Off', 1))
        elif 'KeepAlive' in i:
            tmp.append(i.replace('Off', 'On', 1))
        elif 'Options' in i:
            tmp.append(i.replace('Indexes FollowSymLinks', 'FollowSymLinks', 1))
        elif 'DirectoryIndex' in i:
            tmp.append(i.replace('index.html index.html.var', 'index.php index.html', 1))
        else:
            tmp.append(i)
    file.seek(0)
    for i in tmp:
        file.write(i)
```

It's needlessly complex since I could just use subprocess and sed instead. Any suggestions?

Comment: And why don't you use subprocess and sed?

Comment: Funny.  Are you _bound_ to use python if you can do it alternatively?

Comment: Pythons equivilant of sed: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: Use python config parser, i.e. https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html. Makes things easier!

Comment: Is it true that config parser module does not work with comments? If that's the case, it's out of the question here.

Comment: @PythonNoob: the docs say right there, "Lines beginning with '#' or ';' are ignored and may be used to provide comments."

Comment: Any further suggestions?

Comment: configparser does not save comments on rewrite!! If you wish to maintain comments consider [configobj](http://configobj.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configobj.html) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions inside of Python in very similar way you do this in sed. Just use [Python regular expressions library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). You may be interested in [re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) method, which does equivalent of sed's `s` command used in your example.

If you want to do this efficiently, you probably have to run only one substitute command per line, skipping it if it was changed, similar way you do this in your example code. In order to achieve that, you may use `re.subn` instead of `re.sub` or [re.match](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) combined with groups that were matched.

Here's an example:

```
import re

server_name = 'blah'
webmaster_email = 'blah@blah.com'

SUBS = ( (r'^#ServerName www.example.com', 'ServerName %s' % server_name),
        (r'^ServerAdmin root@localhost', 'ServerAdmin %s' % webmaster_email),
        (r'KeepAlive On', 'KeepAlive Off')
       )

with open("httpd.conf", "r+") as file:
    tmp=[]
    for i in file:
        for s in SUBS:
            ret=re.subn(s[0], s[1], i)
            if ret[1]>0:
                tmp.append(ret[0])
                break
        else:
            tmp.append(i)
    for i in tmp:
        print i,
```

Comment: care to share an example with re.sub or resubn? It's confusing me